# How to animate layer distance from viewer - user - camera change with perspective?

Tags: ios, ios5, animation, core-animation

I'm trying to make an animation very similar to the one at the start of Air bnb iOS app.

Here's a video of the animation : [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_RlPZYIpIY)

The idea is to simulate a layer flying from being very close to the user to end sticking on a far away surface.

I've read some articles talking about manipulating the `layer.transform.m34` and the one that helped me more is [this one](http://milen.me/technical/core-animation-3d-model/).

By applying perspective and a translation on the z-axis, I managed to get the layer look bigger.

Here's the code I used :

```
CALayer *aLayer = [CALayer layer];
aLayer.frame = ...
aLayer.backgroundColor = ...
CATransform3D perspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
perspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0f/-250.0f;
perspectiveTransform.m44 = 0.0f;
perspectiveTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(perspectiveTransform, 0.0f, 0.0f. -100.0f);
aLayer.transform = perspectiveTransform;
```

The problem is I can't get it to animate back to `CATransform3DIdentity` .
I'm not used to CoreAnimation so I may be trying a bad approach.
It would help a lot if someone could point me to what I'm doing wrong or to a better solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is. Why do you need to animate it back to identity? Are you happy with the animation to the transform above?

Comment: @jrturton the identity is the position where it should be laid out at the end of the animation. I want to start the animation with the layer translated in the z-axis with a perspective and finish it with layer with its identity transform (just like in the video). Right now it's not animated, it just looks close (bigger) than the actual frame is.

Comment: Oh, I get you now. Ok. So what do you have so far for the animation? Nothing?

Comment: @jrturton I tried the animation setting the transform to identity but it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create your layer and add it to the layer tree. Once the layer is part of the layer tree then implicit animations should work.

I think you may need to do this:

Create layer
Add layer to parent layer
run remaining animation code with performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: so system gets a chance to add the layer to the layer before your code to do implicit animations is run.